# Exposing to QML the serial port names from C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-creator, qqmllistproperty

I'm trying to expose the QSerialPort.available() through an `Q_INVOKABLE QStringList availablePorts()` function from a class I expose directly to QML in my `main` class.

**Main:**

```
qmlRegisterType<SerialPortManager>("com.MyApp.qml", 1, 0, "SerialPortManager");
```

**SerialPortManager**

```
class SerialPortManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    Q_INVOKABLE virtual QStringList availablePorts() {
        QList<QSerialPortInfo> portsAvailable = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
        QStringList names_PortsAvailable;
        for(QSerialPortInfo portInfo : portsAvailable) {
            names_PortsAvailable.append(portInfo.portName());
        }

        return names_PortsAvailable;
    }
```

Which is not valid for a `model` type in QML because it raises `Unable to assign QStringList to QQmlListModel*` error.

**QML**

```
ComboBox {
    model: serial.availablePorts()
}
SerialPortManager {
    id: serial
}
```

So how do I get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to return a `QVariant` as recommended by the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qstringlist-based-model), for this we use `QVariant::fromValue()`

```
#ifndef SERIALPORTMANAGER_H
#define SERIALPORTMANAGER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QVariant>

class SerialPortManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE static QVariant availablePorts() {
        QList<QSerialPortInfo> portsAvailable = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
        QStringList names_PortsAvailable;
        for(const QSerialPortInfo& portInfo : portsAvailable) {
            names_PortsAvailable<<portInfo.portName();
        }
        return QVariant::fromValue(names_PortsAvailable);
    }
};

#endif // SERIALPORTMANAGER_H
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same exact error. Even though now it's of `QVariant` type.

Comment: @ApostolisAnastasiou How strange, I just tested it, try my code: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/48372528

Comment: https://vimeo.com/252083489 ... Something strange about this. Maybe they changed something on a new version of Qt? Maybe it's a bug?

Comment: @ApostolisAnastasiou What is your version of Qt and OS?

Comment: @ApostolisAnastasiou I saw the problem, do not place it in `public slots:`, move it to `public:`, a slot should not return anything.

Comment: Qt 5.7.0 and OS Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. Yes, your code exactly as you can see in the video.

Comment: @ApostolisAnastasiou if you are going to use Q_INVOKABLE it is not necessary to be a slot

Comment: @ApostolisAnastasiou declare that method under the constructor, you should not declare it in the scope of `public slot`.

Comment: Yeah but even though it was in Slots, it really ... returns `QStringList` error. I tried it on `public` too and happened the same thing.

Comment: @ApostolisAnastasiou Select the Build menu, then press clean all, then run qmake, and just compile, many times the .moc is not modified and generates this type of behavior. Download and try my project directly and you will see that it works

Comment: I'll mark it as solved. Even though I have this problem but I believe you. I tried to clean it. Still same.

Comment: After cloning your repository, I dicsovered that we're running different versions of QtQuick. I'm running **2.0-2.7 maximum** and you're running **2.9** .

Comment: @ApostolisAnastasiou I just tried it with QtQuick 2.0  and QtQuick 2.7 and it also works

Comment: That's true. At least after I updated the QtCreator, it worked. Before as much as I remember it didn't. But mine still doesn't. I really don't know how to respond. Tried different versions of QtQuick and I'm still trying to debug this. Hell ... that's so strange

Comment: @ApostolisAnastasiou I'm suspicious of ComboBox, what version of QtQuick.Controls are you using?

Comment: You were right! It was the ComboBox. I had been using my own custom one, and then I changed to default. It worked. I was using this as a CustomComboBox: https://gist.github.com/Eksapsy/60f38b66f160c5a091e99a098b58e393

So basically the reason was because I had been declaring the model as a `ListModel` instead of a `variant`. So QML is not as type-safe as JS is.

Comment: @ApostolisAnastasiou qml does not do data conversion, QML is not js

Comment: I just a little bit of assumed that because it runs on JavaScript that it would be at least in some cases be similar. Also, I strongly appreciate your time and effort @eyllanesc .

Comment: @ApostolisAnastasiou I recommend you to make each functionality of your project another small project, and when it is workable, when you implement it in your main project, you will save a lot of time as well. :D

Comment: "a slot should not return anything." Slots can return stuff. It's probably easier for others reading your code to understand if you make them Q_INVOKABLE instead, but it's not disallowed.